# import is not working in python3.10, how can i make it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

i have the following folder structure:

```
project:
  src:
    dirA:
      __init__.py
      dirA_file.py
    dirB:
      __init__.py
      utils:
         __init__.py
         utils_file.py
      serve
```

in `utils_file.py` i'm trying to import `class A` from `dirA/dirA_file.py`.
i'm running app from the root(`project` dir), by running `python src/dirB/serve`.

Imports i tried:

```
from src.dirA.dirA_file import A -> error 'No module named "src"'
from ..dirA.dirA_file import A -> error 'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'
from ...dirA.dirA_file import A -> error 'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'
```

looking at similar questions on StackOverflow didn't really make my import work.

Comment: I think you have two options - either change the directory structure such that `dirA` is inside the `dirB` directory, and then use `import dirA.dirA_file` or set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the full path to `src` and do `import dirA.dirA_file`.

Comment: should i set it something like `os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = path to src`. where do i need to set it?

Comment: You should set it in your shell before running the script.  Something like `export PYTHONPATH=/home/name/project/src`

Comment: You can avoid some of the issues by running your script with the `-m` flag, rather than passing the full path of the file to `python`. If you do `python -m src.dirB.serve`, then first two versions of your imports should work. If `src` is not supposed to be your top-level package (but `dirA` and `dirB` are), you probably want to change directories into `src` before running the script with `python -m dirB.serve`. I'd also note that `serve` probably needs a `.py` extension if it's a Python script!

Comment: Check out [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)